# Change mysql code to PDO

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

but i have this project for school,
i need to make a blog with a database connection. 
I have one using mysqli but we are only allowed to use PDO, and in don't know how i can convert it in to PDO can someone help me?

Comment: Can you add an exemple of your code please ?

Comment: I tihnk you should start first with google, where you can find a lot of tutorials about migrating from old mysql* functions to PDO. Afterthat, if you have any problem, let us know, will try to help you.

https://www.google.com/search?q=mysqli+to+pdo&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is difficult to answer as it doesn't contain your code. You'll need to post your code so that people can look at it and point out where the problem is. It would also be very helpful if you could point out *where* exactly you're stuck with this. Also see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You can use the [edit] button to update your question. Good luck!

Comment: If you're only allowed to use PDO, have they at least _taught_ you PDO?  Can you revisit those notes?  Failing that, as others have noted, there are lots of resources around on using it.  A better question would be if/when you've tried something and become stuck with some particular aspect - as it stands this is rather a broad question where answers would just repeat what is already written elsewhere.

Comment: Even rephrasing the question to something I would consider meaningful would be offtopic because of "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam." - though I disagree to some degree with that decsion as there are so many bad tutorials/books available and to vet and rate them is (absolutely) possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good link for you : [Migrate from mysql extension to pdo](http://www.sitepoint.com/migrate-from-the-mysql-extension-to-pdo/)

And take the time to read the PDO manual here : http://php.net/manual/fr/book.pdo.php

Sorry but, I cant give you more specific information if you dont share us the code that gives you trouble.